# Wireless shows up as disabled, how can I get it working?

Tags: 10.04, networking, wireless, network-manager

```
$ sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          
pan0      no wireless extensions.

$
```

This is what pops up when I click the two computers icon

[image]

> Wired Network: disconnected
> Wireless Networks: device not ready

**What should I do to get Wifi working on this machine?**

---

```
$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such file or directory
$

$ lspci | tail
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation ICH9M/M-E SATA AHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc M92 LP [Mobility Radeon HD 4300 Series]
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g (rev 01)
$
```

Comment: The Broadcom driver was missing, it works now, thanks everyone.

Comment: I have this error still in 2024. I spent an hour on research and tests, to no avail. I had to reboot in the end. `lspci | tail` shows `01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 91)`.

Answer (score 8):

It is likely that the network-manager state got corrupted. Open the file `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state`. It should look something like this:

```
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=false
```

Change any from 'false' to 'true' to re-enable networking:

```
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
```

It may work better if you first stop NetworkManager:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

Or:

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
```

And start it again once done:

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

Or:

```
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager
```

If that does not help, reboot.

This happened occasionally after wakeup in Lucid. In Maverick this should be fixed.

Comment: all the states were already set to true. disabling and restarting has no effect.

Comment: In this case, try to remove and re-insert the wireless kernel module with rmmod and modprobe.

Comment: What is the module name?

Comment: This depends on your wifi card. In my case it is iwl4935, I believe.

Comment: Network manager can also be restarted with `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` which in my case looks to be just another reason to thank systemd for fscking linux up and one more good reason to get rid of it

Comment: `lspci | tail` shows, among others: `01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 91)`. Even after changing that NetworkManager.state to `WWANEnabled=true` (works only with `sudo su` rights) and also stopping before and starting after changing, it did not work. Yet, the `false' entry was there. It now remains true. Some first good step to go on with.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

- Install rfkill -> `sudo apt-get install rfkill`
- Give this command in terminal -> `rfkill unblock all`

Your wireless will work instantly, I hope. I guess you have a Intel wireless card and an Hp laptop, one of them at least.

Comment: `rfkill unblock all` does not change anything. I think it is already enabled, but not able to search for the network. I am able to connect to the network using Vista on the same machine though.

Comment: Can you tell me which card is?

Comment: I have this problem on lucid, and this works for me, but the unblock all command only works when I disable wireless on my laptop first (I've got a hardware switch).  So I switch it off, run sudo rfkill unblock all, then switch it on, and it works every time for me.  (Dell Inspiron 1420n)

Answer (score 2):

On my Acer 3500 running ubuntu 10.10 the wireless suddenly stopped working after a screwy suspend/hibernation/power-off event. No amount of reboots would renable it. rfkill said the wireless was turned off at the switch, though the light indicating the wireless card is turned on remained on. `rfkill unblock all` had no effect.

```
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Network manager indicator said "wireless disabled" instead of "device not ready" as in the question. It was greyed out and not possible to change it to enabled. After a couple hours of troubleshooting and research I finally discovered the solution (for me):

```
sudo rm /dev/rfkill && sudo reboot
```

Kudos to *Philip K. Adetiloye* for taking the time to write about in [Ubuntu Wireless disabled: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted](http://pkadetiloye.blogspot.com/2010/11/ubuntu-wireless-disabled-siocsifflags.html). (The error message refers to the output of `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` when /dev/rfkill is in the broken state.)

Comment: sudo rm /dev/rfkill   This worked great for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check this one out. It's for **BROADCOM CARDS ONLY** This worked for me. The button wouldn't work at all, and it wouldn't detect any wireless networks... But I did this, and rebooted, and it works perfectly.

http://techie-buzz.com/foss/wifi-ubuntu-install-broadcom-drivers.html

You might have to mess with the terminal commands, depending on where you put the downloaded files. I kept them all in my "Downloads" folder.

My commands ended up looking like the ones below

> sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware '/home/tsarprodigy/Downloads/wl_apsta-3.130.20.0.o'

Then

> tar xfvj /home/tsarprodigy/Downloads/broadcom-wl-4.80.53.0.tar.bz2'

And finally,

> sudo b43-fwcutter --unsupported -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-4.80.53.0/kmod/wl_apsta_mimo.o

Now all you have to do is restart and it should work just fine!

You're welcome, and thanks for reading...

Answer (score 2):

I did rfkill list and it should no for soft and hard blocks. I still ran rfkill unblock wifi and I was able to see networks again. It has happened to me for the last 2 distros in this manner.

HP DV9000 Laptop

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing any buttons on your keyboard that you're not sure what they do.
I was getting the Hard blocked and look for a wifi switch; didn't see one. Turns out when Ubuntu set-up the keyboard they assigned a button near the bottom of my screen as the wifi button.

Answer (score 1):

I had this (or similar) issue in Ubuntu 10.04. For me, right clicking the network-manager status icon (the two computers), and selecting "Enable wireless" solved the problem for that session.

I had to do this every time I started the machine, though, the solution was workable for me. I never cared to investigate further.

Comment: that checkbox is already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen sometimes, and just right-clicking on the Network Manager applet and re-checking "Enable Wireless" (and/or "Enable Networking") has solved it for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar if not the exact same problem. It seems to be that the WiFi button (rfkill hard block) is not syncing with the rfkill soft block. I had this problem since an Ubuntu update just before Christmas. Before it worked perfectly.

I solved the issue by making sure the hard and soft block are both set to `no`. You can check this by running `rfkill list all` in a terminal.

- The hard block you can change by pressing your laptop's WiFi button
- The soft block you can override by entering `rfkill unblock wifi`

Check with `rfkill list all` if both values are set to `no` and your wireless should work again.

If you still have problems I have written up a bit more detailed [blog post](http://www.geekmind.net/2011/01/linux-wifi-operation-not-possible-due.html).