# wifi works on Windows Vista, but not on Ubuntu

Tags: 10.04, wireless, broadcom

I am not able to connect to Wifi using Ubuntu 10.04, but on the same machine I am able to connect to it using Windows Vista.

I had posted [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9816/wireless-shows-up-as-disabled-how-can-i-get-it-working) about it earlier, but none of the solutions work.

I have the Ubuntu 10.04 LTS CD with me, how can I get Wifi to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried this [post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) it all about broadcom 43xx wifi card install , problem solution, etc

Answer (score 0):

have to tried finding additional drivers?

system-> administration->additional drivers.

you will have to connect to the internet by Ethernet to download the packages for the upgrade to make the driver work.