# Wireless is Disabled

Tags: wireless, network-manager

Recently it's repeated constantly !! Network is Disabled shown in the network icon, my OS ubuntu 10.10 .
While I'm surfing on the NET after a while (may be 2 hours or may be a day) it disconnect and then can't connect to WiFi anymore till rebooting the machine !!.
I've searched and tried a lot of solutions but no useful one seems to solve the probelm :(
 here is one in this [forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9816/wireless-shows-up-as-disabled-how-can-i-get-it-working) it's same problem explained there but can't solve as mentioned !,also every thread/question related to the problem found here I tried but no hope .
"Rfkill list all" command shows:

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

even the Wireless button is switched on !
another command:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

*"lshw" command:

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 01
   serial: 00:19:db:3d:d1:18
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI ip=192.168.1.102 latency=0 multicast=yes
   resources: irq:43 ioport:d800(size=256) memory:fe2ff000-fe2fffff memory:fe2c0000-fe2dffff


 *-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:6
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 00:19:db:9d:d7:c3
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt73usb driverversion=2.6.35-32-generic firmware=N/A multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: vboxnet0
       serial: 0a:00:27:00:00:00
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes multicast=yes
```

*of "lspci" command:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 01)
```

please help....any suggestion will be appreciated .

Comment: Can you add what kind of wireless card it is?

Comment: can "lshw -class network" command be enough !?

Comment: ... ok - also to note (I'm sure you are aware of this already) - support for 10.10 ends in april.  You might want to consider upgrading - this will also have a new kernel which might fix your problem.

Comment: @fossfreedom Thanks, I know that and am waiting the next release 12.04 while the two previous releases were uncomfortable for me ! they confused me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

if `rfkill list` shows `1` is hardblocked:
did you try running

```
rfkill unblock 1
```

that works for me (but in my case i have to run `rfkill unblock 0` and `rfkill unblock 2`, the first is my wireless switch, the second is the wifi switch)

Comment: can't try now till it'll be disabled then I'll feed you back,Thanks.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion Mr.cfstras but it's still disabled !! :(

Comment: what does `rfkill list` say before and after `rfkill unblock`ing?

Answer (score 0):

I would file a bug on launchpad to report this intermittant failure.

In the interim, a few of potential things you can try.

**Suggestion 1.**

Boot using an earlier kernel - press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> at boot time to display your Grub.  Choose the previous versions option and select an older kernel

**Suggestion 2.**

Drop and start your lan connection via

```
ifconfig wlan0 down 
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

**Suggestion 3.**

Force a restart of the network manager service

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

**Suggestion 4.**

Unload and reload the kernel model and restart network manager:

```
sudo modprobe -r rt73usb
sudo modprobe rt73usb
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: nor of them was useful ! but still the first choice I didn't try yet....I'll feed you back.

Comment: Sorry Mr.fossfreedom to be late, No one of above suggestions can solve the problem yet:( but the first not tried yet....here you can check the results of commands < http://www.uploadup.com/di-43PD.png > 4th suggestion disable the whole wireless card and can't reload it any more till reboot the machine :'(.

Comment: Sorry, the 4th seems not to work :(, just the first choice is on ... will feed you back .

Comment: Then with all these suggestions, what would be the problem ?? hardware compatibility ? or what ?

Comment: the rt73usb is very flaky with the maverick kernel. My suggestion would be to investigate a later version of ubuntu to see if the later kernel fixes your issue. You mentioned you dont like unity - Look at my answer here for how to get your old desktop back again in 11.10.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic

Answer (score 0):

Try when booting your computer:

```
 press f2? to get into bios

 press f9? to reset to default settings

press f10? to save settings
```

Check if you're still hard blocked.

[keys are for my laptop which isn't a dell you may need to check which are your own]

Answer (score 0):

For those who tried everything like me, including

```
rfkill list
```

suggested by @cfstras, you might try something ridiculously simple.

In my case `rfkill list` output was:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

So I tried:

```
rfkill unblock 1
```

And this didn't help. After some googling I solved the problem just by pressing `Fn+PrtScr` which has the icon of wireless network. (I have Dell XPS 13 9343, but on your laptop this might be on some other button). HTH.