# Wireless disabled by hardware switch Lenovo Y40

Tags: wireless, lenovo, intel-wireless

I recently got a lenovo Y40 laptop and after i installed ubuntu 14.04 (also in the live usb) Wireless doesn't work. It says that it is disabled by hardware switch, however the hardware switch doesnt work (its intention is to put on airplane mode but does nothing when pressed in ubuntu) wireless works in windows and the BIOS has it enabled. I tried resetting the BIOS but it still doesn't work. Here are some command outputs

lspci:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 93)
```

rfkill list all:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

lswh:

```
   *-network
        description: Ethernet interface
        product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
        logical name: eth0
        version: 10
        serial: f8:a9:63:31:2e:b6
        size: 1Gbit/s
        capacity: 1Gbit/s
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
        resources: irq:64 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c0604000-c0604fff memory:c0600000-c0603fff
*-pci:3
     description: PCI bridge
     product: Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1c.3
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
     version: e4
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=pcieport
     resources: irq:59 memory:c0500000-c05fffff
   *-network DISABLED
        description: Wireless interface
        product: Wireless 3160
        vendor: Intel Corporation
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
        logical name: wlan0
        version: 93
        serial: a0:88:69:90:0a:38
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-32-generic firmware=22.24.8.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
        resources: irq:66 memory:c0500000-c0501fff
```

Comment: try this solutions, specially the one with `rfkill` (http://askubuntu.com/q/9816/86467)

Comment: I have tried to unblock it using rfkill and it hasnt helped it still displays the message that wireless is disabled by wireless switch. Also the other suggestions didn help.

Comment: Also Bluetooth does work i can connect to Bluetooth speakers that I have.

Comment: just incase you missed reboot; after rfkill, you may have to reboot the system.

Comment: Is there any improvement if you temporarily unload ideapad-laptop? sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop

Comment: I rebooted so rfkill wasn´t it. However when i unloaded ideapad-laptop wireless immediately started working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since unloading ideapad-laptop evidently gets the wireless working, let's blacklist it:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r ideapad-laptop
exit
```

You should be all set.