# Lenovo Y40 Wirless issues

Tags: wireless, lenovo, intel-wireless

I cannot seem to get the wireless network card working on my lenovo y40.
I am new to linux so I am pretty lost on how to fix this.

Here is the output of `lshw -C network`:

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 10
   serial: f8:a9:63:31:30:fb
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=10.0.1.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:64 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c0604000-c0604fff memory:c0600000-c0603fff
 *-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 3160
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 93
   serial: a0:88:69:8e:3e:1a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=22.24.8.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:70 memory:c0500000-c0501fff
```

rfkill list all returns -

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not disabled by a hardware switch? Can you also add the output of `rfkill list all`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Unfortunately there is no hardware switch for wireless card on the Y40. Here is rfkill list all:

Comment: What happens if you do: sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop and then: sudo rfkill unblock all Any improvement?

Answer (score 1):

I see this problem on my Lenovo Y40 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and also with Ubuntu 16.02 LTS, both has the same issue and for me the same solutions and it was.
Basically:

echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

modprobe -r ideapad-laptop

exit

Full asnwer and credits, here....

[Wireless disabled by hardware switch Lenovo Y40](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499683/wireless-disabled-by-hardware-switch-lenovo-y40?newreg=b811b4a7e4ff435db9e0403484e692a1)

Comment: When you stumble across a duplicate post like this question, please flag it as a duplicate so that we can erect the appropriate signpost. Thank you! Please review http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled