# Ethernet and Wireless not working on fresh install of Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: drivers, 16.10, intel-wireless

I did a fresh install and could not detect any wireless networks on the laptop.

I ran `dmesg | grep iwl` which told me about my device: `Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210` and also had a few errors about `iwlwifi-7265-ucode-24.ucode` and iwlwifi-7265-ucode-23.ucode` not being able to load.

I google for these 2 files and copied them into `/lib/firmware` and rebooted. Now even the ethernet does not work...

Running `dmesg | grep iwl`:
[image]

Running `dmesg | grep eth`:
[image]

I have no idea at all how to fix it right now, please help!

Edit:
Ran `rfkill list all`:
[image]

Also my laptop is a Lenovo Y520

Comment: `hard blocked: yes` suggests that the wireless switch or key combination is set to disable wireless. You might check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/499683/wireless-disabled-by-hardware-switch-lenovo-y40/499893#499893

Comment: oh wow... I was trying all the keyboard keys in case some hardware switch had to be toggled, just tried this and it worked like a charm!