# Wireless is disabled by hardware

Tags: 14.04, wireless, hardware, broadcom

I tried to use wifi in my notebook but a message appeared "Wireless is disabled by hardware"

I have tried change physical switch, but didn't fix it. And use fn too, but nothing fixed this problem with hardware.

```
   carlos@carlos-pc:~$ sudo rfkill list all
   [sudo] password for carlos: 
   0: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
   1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: yes
```

My hardware is

```
     carlos@carlos-pc:~$ lspci
     00:00.0 Host bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 671MX
     00:01.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] AGP Port (virtual          PCI-to-PCI bridge)
     00:02.0 ISA bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS968 [MuTIOL Media IO] (rev 01)
     00:02.5 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 5513 IDE Controller (rev 01)
     00:03.0 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
     00:03.1 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
     00:03.3 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 2.0 Controller
     00:04.0 Ethernet controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 191 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (rev 02)
     00:05.0 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SATA                   00:06.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
     00:07.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
     00:0b.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)
     00:0b.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)
     00:0b.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 12)
     00:0f.0 Audio device: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] Azalia Audio Controller
     01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter (rev 10)
     02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
```

My notebook is a Philco PHN14005 and I use a Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits.

How can I fix this wifi hardware?

After I did

```
 carlos@carlos-pc:~$ lsmod | grep -e wmi -e laptop
 snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
 snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
 snd                    69322  17       snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_ra     wmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
```

After I use this command

```
 carlos@carlos-pc:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 14e4
 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:04b5]
```

After I use

```
 root@carlos-pc:~# lsmod | grep -e b43 -e wl
 b43                   387371  0 
 bcma                   52096  1 b43
 mac80211              630669  2 b43,ath9k_htc
 cfg80211              484040  4 b43,ath,mac80211,ath9k_htc
 ssb                    62379  1 b43

  carlos@carlos-pc:~$ lsmod
  Module                  Size  Used by
  ath9k                 164164  0 
  bnep                   19624  2 
  rfcomm                 69160  0 
  bluetooth             391136  10 bnep,rfcomm
  arc4                   12608  4 
  ath9k_htc              95963  0 
  ath9k_common           13551  2 ath9k,ath9k_htc
  b43                   387371  0 
  ath9k_hw              453856  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_htc
  ath                    28698  4 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_htc,ath9k_hw
  uvcvideo               80885  0 
  videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
  videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
  videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
  bcma                   52096  1 b43
  videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
  mac80211              630669  3 b43,ath9k,ath9k_htc
  snd_hda_codec_si3054    13008  1 
  snd_hda_codec_realtek    65580  1 
  snd_hda_intel          56451  3 
  snd_hda_codec         192906  3       snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_intel
  snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
  snd_pcm               102099  3       snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
  snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
  snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
  snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
  snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
  cfg80211              484040  5 b43,ath,ath9k,mac80211,ath9k_htc
  snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
  snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
  snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
  coretemp               13435  0 
  snd                    69322  17       snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_ra      wmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
  joydev                 17381  0 
  serio_raw              13462  0 
  r592                   18023  0 
  soundcore              12680  1 snd
  memstick               16966  1 r592
  video                  19476  0 
  mac_hid                13205  0 
  sis_agp                13283  1 
  shpchp                 37032  0 
  parport_pc             32701  0 
  ppdev                  17671  0 
  lp                     17759  0 
  parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
  hid_generic            12548  0 
  usbhid                 52659  0 
  hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid
  pata_acpi              13038  0 
  firewire_ohci          40409  0 
  psmouse               106714  0 
  ssb                    62379  1 b43
  sis190                 22626  0 
  firewire_core          68769  1 firewire_ohci
  sdhci_pci              23172  0 
  sdhci                  43015  1 sdhci_pci
  crc_itu_t              12707  1 firewire_core
  sata_sis               12823  1 
  mii                    13934  1 sis190
```

Comment: Is this a dual boot system?

Comment: @xangua yes, I use Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried to boot to Windows, enable Wi-Fi and reboot to ubuntu?

Comment: yes, but didn't fix nothing

Comment: Just fix the TPlink usb adapter

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` and then `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` and reboot.  If it doesn't work after reboot add the results from `lsmod | grep -e wmi -e laptop`

Comment: I did this command, please see above the results.

Comment: Does it still show a hard block from `rfkill list all` and not change with the position of the switch?  And just for good measure what is the result of `lspci -nnk | grep 14e4`

Comment: Please, see the results above. It didn't fix it.

Comment: The correct module should be loaded but we should check `lsmod | grep -e b43 -e wl` as the post http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110 says that the wl module is not recommended for you chipset and b43 with the firmware works

Comment: Ok, but what I have to do?

Comment: Please show `lsmod | grep -e b43 -e wl` as the wl module might have been installed using a different package name

Comment: Ok, see above again the results

Comment: Only 1 idea left unless `lsmod` shows something unexpected `sudo modprobe -r ath9k` and then `sudo rfkill unblock all` and then `sudo modprobe ath9k`  Post complete `lsmod` results and hopefully something shows up but it could be a issue with the switch

Comment: Ok, I did, please see the result above.

Comment: I would reboot and enter BIOS to reset to default and then boot.  You might want to see if there is a BIOS update for this computer

Comment: how can I update my BIOS?

Comment: You will have to visit the manufacturers website and look for downloads for your model.  Most likely Windows will be needed to do the update

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try out the below command

sudo rmmod -f dell-laptop

sudo rfkill unblock all

Check whether it worked

Comment: No, didn't fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be similar to your problem.

[Wireless shows up as disabled, how can I get it working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9816/wireless-shows-up-as-disabled-how-can-i-get-it-working)

solution was:

```
sudo rm /dev/rfkill && sudo reboot
```

Comment: This command didn't fix it.